# If menstruation has ended before sunrise in Ramadan is it accepted to fast, if one had eaten before the ghusl?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, ghusl, menses

If my menstruation has ended before sunrise and I had taken shower ghusl, but before that I had eaten on time for sahur is it accepted as fast?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

asalamoalikum wrwb

according to hanafi fiqh if you were in the end of menstruation during ramadan and in night you were sure that next morning your menses would end before fajr and you made an intention of fast in night and when in morning u observed no blood then ur fast is valid if u had taken bath before zawal time jazakillah wallahualam warasuluhu

Answer (score 1):

The point is if the menstruation ended before dawn (this means before the fajr adhan) then there's a consensus that you must fast, even if you didn't perform the ghusl before the dawn! So you must specify what you exactly mean by sunrise, because sunrise is usually a time after dawn.

If the menstruation (truly) ended in the day (after dawn) of Ramadan then

- most scholars (Imam Malik, Imam Ash-Shafi'i and Imam Ahmad in one of his statements) say that any body who was allowed to eat at the beginning of the day shouldn't fast according to a narration (not a hadith!) from ibn Masu'd (may Allah be pleased with him) saying

  > " من أكل أول النهار فليأكل آخره  who ate at the beginning of the day (this means after dawn) have to eat at the end of the day (this means sunset)"

As an Answer for the Question saying: "A man who did suhur thinking it is night and found out that dawn has already past".
By the way they also take the Verse [187](http://legacy.quran.com/2/187) from surat al-Baqara (2) as a reference which states when one has the end and beginning times of fast!

As an example of practice a Tabi'i called abu Sha'ta' أبو الشعثاء  came from a journey back home in Ramadan while his wife just made ghusl from menstruation and they had a physical relationship as narrated by Jabir ibn Yazyd جابر بن يزيد.

- Imam Abu Hanifa and Imam Ahamd in his 2nd statement (and also the imams at-Thawry and al Awza'y) say they must fast the rest of the day and repeat the day (qada'). Here they assume that the person concerned knows that he/she will move from a person who is allowed not to fast (because of some conditions, menstruation, travel for instance) to a person who legally has to fast during day time, but this qiyas is considered to be kind of weak!

(See also this [Fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/126918) and [here س 2‏:](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86%20%D8%B3%D8%A4%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D8%B9%D9%86%20%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%B6%20**/%D8%B3%207:%20%D8%A5%D8%B0%D8%A7%20%D8%B7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B6%20%D8%A3%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%81%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%AC%D8%B1%20%D9%88%D9%84%D9%85%20%D8%AA%D8%BA%D8%AA%D8%B3%D9%84%20%D8%A5%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%AC%D8%B1%20%D9%87%D9%84%20%D9%8A%D8%B5%D8%AD%20%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%85%D9%87%D8%A7%20%D8%A3%D9%85%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%9F%20/i177&d92966&c&p1) in Arabic or [here](https://islamqa.info/en/68829))

So if your menstruation has ended before the dawn and you fasted then your fast is accepted (and correct) and it was obligatory for you no matter if you performed the ghusl before dawn or later.

Answer (score -1):

It is not permitted for menstruating woman to fast. Because fasting starts from dawn, and that your menstruation was still there at that time, your fast will not be accepted. You should make up for that fast.

Ibn Qudaamah said in al-Mughni (4/397):

> The scholars are unanimously agreed that it is not permissible for
>   women who are menstruating or bleeding following childbirth to fast,
>   and that they should not fast in Ramadaan but should make up missed
>   fasts. If they do fast, their fast is not accepted. ‘Aa’ishah said:
>   “We used to menstruate at the time of the Messenger of Allaah (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him), and we were commanded to make up
>   the fasts, but we were not commanded to make up the prayers.” Agreed
>   upon.  The one who commanded them thus was the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him). Abu Sa’eed said: The Prophet (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Is it not the case that
>   when one of you menstruates, she does not pray or fast? That is what
>   is meant by lacking in religious commitment.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari.