# My husband and I were met after few months in ramadan and we skipped fasting because we wanted to have intercourse. Does this also requires kafarrah?

Tags: intercourse

My husband and myself are married but we stay in different states due to some reasons, and we meet occasionally after some months. We once met during ramadan and we both decided not to fast because we wanted to have intercourse. Is this also a sin and requires expiation?

Comment: This needs further explanation: You can't intentionally skip fasting without an excuse since fasting is due on you it would be even a major sin. But if you have a valid excuse you can break your fast. So please edit your post using the edit link at the bottom of it left-hand side and tell us exactly what happened. See also [If menstruation has ended before sunrise in Ramadn is it accepted into fast if one had eaten before the ghusl?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25252/if-menstruation-has-ended-before-sunrise-in-ramadan-is-it-accepted-to-fast-if-o)

Answer (score 1):

It's a major sin. You guys should have wait till maghrib. And as far as expiation then ask a real scholar, try islamqa.info or shaikh assim al hakim website.